# Redirect a.com/suffix to b.com

Tags: redirect, github, dns, cname

*Context: I'm developing a website for a conference happening early next year. I'm using tito.io to process registrations and Github Pages to host the website.*

At the moment, users register by visiting `https://tito.io/maine-civic-hack-day/maine-civic-hack-day-2013`. I'd like to clean that up, and point them to `http://mainecivichackday.com/register` instead.

I've read about 301, 302, and masked redirects, but as far as I've seen so far, those are applicable to subdomains. For instance, I can make this work with `register.mainecivichackday.com`, but not with `mainecivichackday.com/register`.

What are my options?

***TLDR**: how do I point `a.com/b` to `c.com`?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set up a redirect on the a.com/b page to b.com/a but the user will see that they were redirected to.

If you want it to show as a clean url to the user, the webserver at tito.io will have to be configured to answer to your desired url such as http://register.mainecivichackday.com